# Issues loading and using chemmacros

Tags: incompatibility, chemmacros

I need to draw a few molecular hybrid orbitals and I'm going to use `chemmacros`.

I've been reading about compatibility  issues existing with this package, but I cannot get it loaded in anyway.

Using the [chemmacros](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/chemmacros/chemmacros_en.pdf) documentation examples:

This is the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}

\begin{document}

 \setbondoffset{0pt}
 \chemsetup[orbital]{
   overlay ,
   opacity = .75 ,
   p/scale = 1.6 ,
   s/color = blue!50 ,
   s/scale = 1.6
 }
 \chemfig{\orbital{s}-[:-20]{\orbital[scale=2]{p}}{\orbital[half,angle=0]{p}}{\orbital[angle=170,half]{p}}{\orbital[angle=-150,half]{p}}(-[:-150]\orbital{s})-\orbital{s}}

\end{document}
```

When compile this I get this output log:

http://ix.io/1v84

Screenshot of error messages and code:
[image]

Comment: Please put the errors in textual form and  add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: I hope the changes will help you to reproduce my issue.

Comment: Indeed it would be better to include the code as text, then somebody who wants to answer does not have to re-type everything. Luckily this example is taken from the `chemmacros` manual, which allows to copy-paste the code. You can probably solve the issue by putting `\chemsetup{modules=orbital}` _before_ `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Thank you, @Marijn, that was the solution, where is this specified in the chemmacros docu?

Comment: This is described in Section 3.1 of the manual, however the manual is not very clear about this so it is completely understandable that you missed it.

Comment: And thanks for the MWE, it is a good one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely missed out the 3.1 section in the [chemmacros docu](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/chemmacros/chemmacros_en.pdf). So adding

```
\chemsetup{modules=all}
```

in the preamble, the problem fixes. Like this picture shows
[image]